# working with dll ocx in delphi

Tags: delphi, dll

i´m trying to use 2 a dll (OCX) in my application but when i want to call a function how can i do soo?

how can i call this funcion 
`RSDKLib_TLB.IID_IMeasurement`....  "TGUID"???

in the dll is

```
 IID_IMeasurement: TGUID = '{97E75BE0-AF26-4E4A-B651-C5DDECEC2936}';
```

or is the approach wrong??

Comment: I have little experience with COM, so I'll put this in a comment: Your OCX DLL implements an COM-based control; From Delphi go to Components -> Import ActiveX, find your control and import it. Delphi will generate all required stuff to put that control onto your component pallet, you'll then be able to drop it onto a form and use it. Of course, there might be countless complications to this, but I'm not the COM expert so I don't know.

Comment: The thing you've shown is not a function at all. What makes you think you're supposed to *call* it? What reference material are you using for your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you may need some basic introduction to COM Programming.

It sounds like you have imported the library.   But you need to learn how to call the functions that holds.

First off look at the bottom of the import unit (right above the implementation keyword) you will find several classes named CoXXX where XXX is usually the name of the interface you want to create.

The CoXXX Classes will look like this:

```
  CoXXX = class
    class function Create: IXXX;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): IXXX;
  end;
```

So taking a guess at the information you have provided.

```
var
 M : IMeasurement;
begin
 M := CoIMeasurement.Create
 M.MethodYouNeedToCall;
end;
```

Comment: do you mean here??

/ *********************************************************************//
// GUIDS declared in the TypeLibrary. Following prefixes are used:        
//   Type Libraries     : LIBID_xxxx                                      
//   CoClasses          : CLASS_xxxx                                      
//   DISPInterfaces     : DIID_xxxx                                       
//   Non-DISP interfaces: IID_xxxx

Comment: i try like this
var
 M : IImage2Disp;
begin
  M := TIRSDK.Create;// here i have , ot enough actual parameters Why??
 M.TempUnit:= 1000;
end;

Thank´s

Comment: I´starting so what is the simple way to call:
*********************************************************************//
// DispIntf: IImage2Disp
// Flags: (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID: {D9DC4473-CCB9-46FF-A063-4D72B8495F29}
// *********************************************************************//
IImage2Disp = dispinterface
['{D9DC4473-CCB9-46FF-A063-4D72B8495F29}']

property TempUnit: Smallint dispid 24;
property TempUnitStr: WideString readonly dispid 25;
property DistUnitStr: WideString readonly dispid 26;

Comment: I try to get the value from the dll but gave me a erros and stop

procedure TForm8.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Intf: IImage2;
   begin
   iRSDK1.Connect;
 edit1.Text := Intf.OutputUnitStr;
end;

what i´m doing wrong
Ml

Comment: Intf has not been created when you are using it.   iRSDXK1 may also be in the same boat.

Comment: I+m tryng but really not yet found the solution is somenoe can help
my source with DLL is here
http://www.4shared.com/file/thBMxY2G/carregactx.html